# Can't Generate Full Range of Random for Integers

Tags: c++, file-io, random, ifstream

I am trying to generate a file of 10000 integers between 0 and 100 000 so I can do a MergeSort on them later.

When I generate the file using fstream, I never get an integer over 32760.

The following method generates the file and then reads it back and checks for any integer over 32750. I usually get between 3-5 integers between 32750 and 32760. Why does this happen and how can I fix it? Is it a seed problem or the actual use of the Random function?

```
// sizeOfArray = 10000
void generateFile() {
    ofstream fout("unsorted.txt");
    srand(time(NULL));

    // Generating the file
    int num;
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++) {
         num = rand() % 100000;
         if(i < sizeOfArray-1)
            //fout << i+1 << ": " << num << endl;
            fout << num << endl;
         else
            //fout << i+1 << ": " << num;
            fout << num;
    }

    // Reading the File Back
    ifstream fin("unsorted.txt");
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++) {
        fin >> num;
        if(num > 32750)
            cout << num << endl;
    }

    cin.get();
}
```

**SOLVED**
Using the answer provided below I generated the file 500 times 
and the highest Integer I received was 99931.

Comment: That is the range of the random number generator. Use a different random number generator, or take two random numbers and combine them into a single one.

Comment: According to cplusplus.com, the range for `rand()` is `0 - RAND_MAX`. `RAND_MAX` is library dependent, but should be atleast `32767`.

Comment: Do you know of a random number generator that would give me the range I need?

Comment: It looks like you are using 16 bit signed integers, the maximum value that these can express is just over 32760. (32767 to be precise)

Comment: P.S. This is actually a good question - in this day and age it's not obvious that the range of random numbers should be so small. The limit you ran into would have been more appropriate 20 years ago.

Comment: Adding 3 random numbers won't give you an equal distribution. It's the same reason rolling two dice is more likely to give you a 7 than a 2.

Comment: @CodesInChaos These are increasingly hard to come by ([link 1](http://xkcd.com/221/), [link 2](http://search.dilbert.com/comic/Random%20Number%20Generator)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The highest random value that you can get from `rand()` is `RAND_MAX`, a library-dependent constant. In your case, it appears to be set to `2^15-1`, the highest positive number that fits in a signed 16-bit integer.

When you need to generate numbers that are larger than `RAND_MAX`, call `rand()` several times, each time multiplying by `RAND_MAX`. For example, in your case the following code should work (I am assuming that your `int` has 32 bits):

```
num = rand();
num *= RAND_MAX;
num += rand();
num %= 100000;
```

Note that merely adding three random numbers together to get the desired range will not produce the same random distribution as multiply and add approach.

Comment: Why is the line num += rand() included? I tried it without that line and still received ints very close to 100 000.

Comment: @Gander7: If you don't do `num += rand()`, your results (before modding) are always going to be a multiple of `RAND_MAX`.  You also can think of it this way: if `RAND_MAX` is a power of two, it'd be the equivalent of doing left-shifts and ORs to set sections of bits separately.

Comment: Ah, Even though rand() was already used once, without that line I will still only be able to get 32767 numbers. They will be the original 32767 * RAND_MAX. The second Rand() is to diversify the result. @jamesdlin Thanks.

Comment: @Gander7 Imagine a `rand()` that returns values from 0 to 99. Let's say you need a number 0..9999. The right way of doing it is `rand()*100+rand()`: the first `rand()` fills in the top two digits, and the second fills in the bottom two digits. You can use just `rand()*100`, but then you'd never get a number from 0 to 99, from 100 to 199, from 200 to 299, and so on.

Comment: BTW, I'm not a fan of doing `% 100000` to get random numbers in the [0, 100000) range since it introduces bias and because of http://www.c-faq.com/lib/notveryrand.html

Comment: @jamesdlin I agree. However, for the purposes of generating a file for testing a sort algorithm this should be good enough.

Answer (score 3):

You can use one of the new random number generators introduced with C++11 to get a larger range: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

If you don't have C++11 you can also get it from Boost: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_random.html

Comment: `rand()` is a hopeless case, switch to one of these.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you are using: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/RAND_MAX/